# Switched routers, now firefox and terminal can't find sites, but Chrome and Tor can

Tags: command-line, networking, firefox, router, ping

Running 16.04 with a Ethernet connection to my router.

Today switched routers to get a DD-WRT one going.  Now Firefox, Thunderbird, terminal (ping), and a few other programs can't find hosts.

This works on the same machine booted into Windows, and works fine with Chrome on the Ubuntu install.  I've rebooted the machine several times, as well as attempting to reset the network adapter.

Any ideas?  All ping gives me is "ping: unknown host " for anything remote.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it does not sound like you are a novice in the world of networking, I would like to piont to the obvious: DNS

Are you sure that your new router is actually set up to provide DNS information? Perhaps the Windows system handles this at connection level and therefore does not care that the router is not handing out this information.'

I would suggest to try to ping an outside IP address instead of a domain name, e.g. ping 8.8.8.8
If this gives positive results then you know that you have contact with the outside world and that it is name resolving that is the issue.

Comment: Thanks!  I believe that is it - pinging google.com fails, ping 8.8.8.8 works.

I'd previously tried flushing the DNS cache.  The router isn't the issue - I've actually replaced it with the old, and still have the issue - not to mention Chrome can access DNS, while Firefox and Terminal can't.

I'll try another flush of DNS - any tips on a good way to do that?

Comment: I am not using chrome myself, but an Internet search suggests that Chrome automatically use Google's DNS server instead of system determined DNS. This would explain why this browser works and not Firefox.

Comment: When obtaining a dynamic IP via DHCP, DNS information should also be relayed to the client. Are you using a static IP on your ubuntu system and a dynamic IP on the Windows system? In case you are using a static IP, you must setup DNS information manually for that connection.

Comment: Running 'nmcli device show | grep DNS' should provide information about DNS settings for your connection.

Comment: Thanks Kristian - output of the command is 

IP4.DNS[1]:                             208.67.222.222
IP4.DNS[2]:                             208.67.220.220
IP4.DNS[3]:                             167.206.13.180


I believe my IP is dynamic on both systems.   I've added the Google DNS server as an additional one (and set it at the router level), but no success there.